# Linux OOM: Trying to understand memory statistics / mismatch with expected values

Tags: linux, memory, kvm-virtualization, proxmox, oom

I am trying to understand why the OOM killer has reaped a process on a KVM virtual machine running with 1 gigabyte of memory. While I do already know that running Linux machines without swap is not the best idea, I am trying to understand why the process reap has happened.

First of all, here is the kernel log containing all the information I have got from the OOM killer:

```
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948247] tor invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24201ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE|__GFP_COLD), nodemask=0, order=0,     oom_score_adj=0
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948247] tor cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948251] CPU: 0 PID: 1439 Comm: tor Not tainted 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948251] Hardware name: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.10.2-0-g5f4c7b1-prebuilt.qemu-project.org 04/    01/2014
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948252]  0000000000000000 ffffffffb2129134 ffffc4b4801afc28 ffffa0d89a244100
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948254]  ffffffffb1ffe340 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000c024213ca
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948255]  ffffffffb1f84517 000000429a244100 ffffffffc0615695 0000000000000001
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948257] Call Trace:
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948261]  [<ffffffffb2129134>] ? dump_stack+0x5c/0x78
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948263]  [<ffffffffb1ffe340>] ? dump_header+0x78/0x1fd
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948264]  [<ffffffffb1f84517>] ? get_page_from_freelist+0x3f7/0xb40
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948268]  [<ffffffffc0615695>] ? virtballoon_oom_notify+0x25/0x70 [virtio_balloon]
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948269]  [<ffffffffb1f804aa>] ? oom_kill_process+0x21a/0x3e0
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948271]  [<ffffffffb1f8012d>] ? oom_badness+0xed/0x170
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948272]  [<ffffffffb1f80941>] ? out_of_memory+0x111/0x470
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948273]  [<ffffffffb1f85bb7>] ? __alloc_pages_slowpath+0xbb7/0xbf0
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948274]  [<ffffffffb1f85dee>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x1fe/0x260
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948277]  [<ffffffffb1fd6151>] ? alloc_pages_current+0x91/0x140
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948278]  [<ffffffffb1f7e940>] ? filemap_fault+0x300/0x5a0
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948290]  [<ffffffffc05677e1>] ? ext4_filemap_fault+0x31/0x50 [ext4]
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948293]  [<ffffffffb1faef81>] ? __do_fault+0x81/0x170
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948294]  [<ffffffffb1fb36c0>] ? handle_mm_fault+0xd80/0x12d0
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948296]  [<ffffffffb2001827>] ? new_sync_read+0xd7/0x120
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948297]  [<ffffffffb1e5ed9c>] ? __do_page_fault+0x25c/0x500
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948299]  [<ffffffffb2408a48>] ? async_page_fault+0x28/0x30
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948299] Mem-Info:
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948301] active_anon:125187 inactive_anon:2602 isolated_anon:0
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948301]  active_file:95 inactive_file:1644 isolated_file:0
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948301]  unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:8 unstable:0
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948301]  slab_reclaimable:4702 slab_unreclaimable:11348
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948301]  mapped:1458 shmem:2652 pagetables:804 bounce:0
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948301]  free:12103 free_pcp:89 free_cma:0
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948303] Node 0 active_anon:500748kB inactive_anon:10408kB active_file:380kB inactive_file:6576kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:5832kB     dirty:0kB writeback:32kB shmem:10608kB shmem_thp: 0kB shmem_pmdmapped: 0kB anon_thp: 0kB writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB pages_scanned:374512 all_unreclaimable?     yes
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948303] Node 0 DMA free:4124kB min:716kB low:892kB high:1068kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB     present:15992kB managed:15908kB mlocked:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:1096kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB     free_cma:0kB
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948305] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 959 959 959 959
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948307] Node 0 DMA32 free:44288kB min:44336kB low:55420kB high:66504kB active_anon:500748kB inactive_anon:10408kB active_file:380kB inactive_file:6576kB unevictable:0kB     writepending:32kB present:1032048kB managed:1004452kB mlocked:0kB slab_reclaimable:18808kB slab_unreclaimable:44296kB kernel_stack:1232kB pagetables:3216kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:356kB local_pcp:356kB     free_cma:0kB
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948309] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0 0
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948310] Node 0 DMA: 217*4kB (U) 171*8kB (U) 98*16kB (U) 0*32kB 1*64kB (U) 0*128kB 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB =     4124kB
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948315] Node 0 DMA32: 2150*4kB (UMEH) 2083*8kB (UMEH) 1189*16kB (UMEH) 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB =     44288kB
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948320] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=1048576kB
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948321] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0 hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948321] 4401 total pagecache pages
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948322] 0 pages in swap cache
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948323] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948323] Free swap  = 0kB
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948323] Total swap = 0kB
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948324] 262010 pages RAM
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948324] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948324] 6920 pages reserved
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948324] 0 pages hwpoisoned
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948325] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948328] [  437]     0   437    14212      372      24       3        0             0     systemd-journal
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948329] [  467]     0   467    11493      313      24       3        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948330] [  598]     0   598     3005      782      11       3        0             0 haveged
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948331] [  603]     0   603    37702    11634      80       3        0             0 salt-minion
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948332] [  605]     0   605    62529      306      27       3        0             0 rsyslogd
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948333] [  609]     0   609    11618      141      27       3        0             0     systemd-logind
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948334] [  612]   105   612    11283      117      26       3        0          -900 dbus-daemon
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948335] [  620]     0   620     7483       62      19       3        0             0 cron
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948336] [  621]     0   621    17486      189      37       3        0         -1000 sshd
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948337] [  633]     0   633     3708       34      12       3        0             0 agetty
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948338] [  716]     0   716   130502    15306     119       4        0             0 salt-minion
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948339] [  734]   107   734    25516      143      24       3        0             0 ntpd
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948340] [  738]     0   738    66842    12779      96       3        0             0 salt-minion
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948341] [ 1439]   109  1439   139276    93739     245       3        0             0 tor
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948342] Out of memory: Kill process 1439 (tor) score 368 or sacrifice child
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.948364] Killed process 1439 (tor) total-vm:557104kB, anon-rss:374956kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Jan  4 10:04:40 <host> kernel: [53542.966776] oom_reaper: reaped process 1439 (tor), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB,     shmem-rss:0kB
```

I have now tried to find the culprit by converting the amount of pages to the usage of memory in MiB (x 4 / 1024) for all the different memory statistics:

```
MemInfo Name            Pages   Memory in MiB
active_anon             125187  489.0117188
inactive_anon           2602    10.1640625
active_file             95      0.37109375
inactive_file           1644    6.421875
writeback               8       0.03125
slam_reclaimable        4702    18.3671875
slab_unreclaimable      11348   44.328125
mapped                  1458    5.6953125
shmem                   2652    10.359375
pagetables              804     3.140625
pagecache               4401    17.19140625
```

But even if I add all those numbers together I will only end up with a usage of around 600 MiB. When just using the sum of all "rss" values of the process table printed by the OOM killer, I even end up with only 135917 pages (~530 MiB).

Now if we subtract that calculated number from the total amount of memory (e.g. 996MiB - 600MiB in the worst case based on the numbers from above), we still end up with more than 300MiB of theoretically usable memory, however within the kernel log "free:44288kB" states that only ~44MiB of memory are left.

Why is there a difference and what did I miss? Are there any other memory allocations that have to be taken into account which are using up that space?

**EDIT 1:** I want to mention that the hypervisor itself has 32GB of memory and only runs that single VM at the moment. There are over 20GB of memory available according to meminfo/free/top and the other few GBs are used for caching.

**EDIT 2:** As per request, I will hereby list the kernel modules active on the hypervisor system which is running Proxmox with ZFS storage:

```
acpi_pad, aes_x86_64, aesni_intel, ahci, ast, autofs4, binfmt_misc, coretemp, crc32_pclmul, crct10dif_pclmul, cryptd, crypto_simd, dca, drm, drm_kms_helper, e1000e, fb_sys_fops, ghash_clmulni_intel, glue_helper, gre, hid, hid_generic, i2c_algo_bit, i2c_i801, ib_cm, ib_core, ib_iser, icp, ie31200_edac, igb, inet_diag, input_leds, intel_cstate, intel_pch_thermal, intel_powerclamp, intel_rapl, intel_rapl_perf, ip6_tables, ip6table_filter, ip_gre, ip_set, ip_tables, ip_tunnel, ipmi_devintf, ipmi_msghandler, ipmi_si, ipmi_ssif, iptable_filter, irqbypass, iscsi_tcp, iw_cm, joydev, kvm, kvm_intel, libahci, libcrc32c, libiscsi, libiscsi_tcp, lpc_ich, mac_hid, mei, mei_me, nf_conntrack, nf_conntrack_ipv4, nf_conntrack_ipv6, nf_conntrack_proto_gre, nf_defrag_ipv4, nf_defrag_ipv6, nf_nat, nf_nat_ipv4, nf_nat_ipv6, nfnetlink, nfnetlink_log, nls_iso8859_1, openvswitch, pcbc, pcspkr, pps_core, ptp, rdma_cm, scsi_transport_iscsi, shpchp, softdog, spl, sunrpc, syscopyarea, sysfillrect, sysimgblt, tap, tcp_diag, ttm, usbhid, usbkbd, usbmouse, vhost, vhost_net, video, x86_pkg_temp_thermal, x_tables, zavl, zcommon, zfs, znvpair, zunicode
```

Also, these are the kernel modules loaded within the affected VM:

```
ablk_helper, aes_x86_64, aesni_intel, ata_generic, ata_piix, autofs4, binfmt_misc, bochs_drm, button, cdrom, crc16, crc32_pclmul, crc32c_generic, crc32c_intel, crct10dif_pclmul, cryptd, drm, drm_kms_helper, ecb, ehci_hcd, evdev, ext4, floppy, fscrypto, gf128mul, ghash_clmulni_intel, glue_helper, hid, hid_generic, i2c_piix4, ip6_tables, ip6t_REJECT, ip6table_filter, ip_set, ip_set_hash_net, ip_set_list_set, ip_tables, ipmi_msghandler, ipmi_watchdog, ipt_REJECT, iptable_filter, jbd2, joydev, libata, lrw, mbcache, nf_conntrack, nf_conntrack_ipv4, nf_conntrack_ipv6, nf_defrag_ipv4, nf_defrag_ipv6, nf_log_common, nf_log_ipv4, nf_log_ipv6, nf_reject_ipv4, nf_reject_ipv6, nfnetlink, parport, parport_pc, pcspkr, ppdev, psmouse, scsi_mod, sd_mod, serio_raw, sg, shpchp, sr_mod, ttm, uhci_hcd, usb_common, usbcore, usbhid, virtio, virtio_balloon, virtio_net, virtio_pci, virtio_ring, virtio_scsi, x_tables, xt_addrtype, xt_comment, xt_conntrack, xt_limit, xt_LOG, xt_multiport, xt_recent, xt_tcpudp
```

Last but not least, the command line which is being used for launching the virtual machine:

```
/usr/bin/kvm -id 100 -chardev socket,id=qmp,path=/var/run/qemu-server/100.qmp,server,nowait -mon chardev=qmp,mode=control -pidfile /var/run/qemu-server/100.pid -daemonize -smbios type=1,uuid=<censored> -name <censored> -smp 1,sockets=1,cores=1,maxcpus=1 -nodefaults -boot menu=on,strict=on,reboot-timeout=1000,splash=/usr/share/qemu-server/bootsplash.jpg -vga std -vnc unix:/var/run/qemu-server/100.vnc,x509,password -cpu host,+kvm_pv_unhalt,+kvm_pv_eoi -m 1024 -k en-us -device pci-bridge,id=pci.2,chassis_nr=2,bus=pci.0,addr=0x1f -device pci-bridge,id=pci.1,chassis_nr=1,bus=pci.0,addr=0x1e -device piix3-usb-uhci,id=uhci,bus=pci.0,addr=0x1.0x2 -device usb-tablet,id=tablet,bus=uhci.0,port=1 -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -iscsi initiator-name=iqn.1993-08.org.debian:01:f4b280ed945d -drive if=none,id=drive-ide2,media=cdrom,aio=threads -device ide-cd,bus=ide.1,unit=0,drive=drive-ide2,id=ide2,bootindex=200 -device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsihw0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5 -drive file=/dev/zvol/rpool/srv/vmdata/vm-100-disk-1,if=none,id=drive-scsi0,discard=on,format=raw,cache=none,aio=native,detect-zeroes=unmap -device scsi-hd,bus=scsihw0.0,channel=0,scsi-id=0,lun=0,drive=drive-scsi0,id=scsi0,bootindex=100 -netdev type=tap,id=net0,ifname=tap100i0,script=/var/lib/qemu-server/pve-bridge,downscript=/var/lib/qemu-server/pve-bridgedown,vhost=on -device virtio-net-pci,mac=<censored>,netdev=net0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x12,id=net0,bootindex=300
```

Comment: Looks at first glance like the KVM host has overcommitted RAM and is running out.

Comment: @Michael Hampton Thanks for your comment. I have updated the question to clarify that the host has more than enough RAM available.

Comment: Can you provide a list of kernel modules that are active too?

Comment: Also, a description of the VM hardware (if using libvirt the xml for that is fine) or the qemu command line you invoked.

Comment: @matthew-ife I have added a list of kernel modules active on both hypervisor and guest. Additionally, I have provided the command line which is being generated by Proxmox for spawning the virtual machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still cannot comment so I'll try to create something like an answer. First, take a look at these sources:

- http://bl0rg.krunch.be/oom-frag.html
- https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/KernelMemoryZones

The memory zone which triggered the OOM killer was DMA32:

```
Node 0 DMA32 free:44288kB min:44336kB low:55420kB high:66504kB
```

As I understand this and your log shows it's possible, your server's memory is fragmented:

```
Node 0 DMA32: 2150*4kB (UMEH) 2083*8kB (UMEH) 1189*16kB (UMEH) 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB =     44288kB
```

The largest available page is 16kB.

You may take a look at your current memory fragmentation:

```
cat /proc/buddyinfo
cat /proc/pagetypeinfo
```

[Here](http://tomoyo.osdn.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) is an explanation of both files and their content.

Comment: Its not this. The page being requested is Order 0 in the OOM log, thats a 4kb page. In fact, theres literally only ~50MiB of actual free pages.

Comment: Oh, good, I can comment my own answer! :-)
Do you know how much memory your kernel uses?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97261/how-much-ram-does-the-kernel-use